# Why are SQL Server Identity Columns Immutable?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do some setting up of a new database by modifying an existing database.  I see that if I try to do an update statement to modify the primary key, sql server will give the following error:

```
Cannot update identity column 'columnname'.
```

I can see that I will have to work around this, but I'm wondering, why does SQL Server have this restriction in the first place?  It lets us insert into an identity column ok, then why not UPDATE?

Answer (score 2):

Identity columns are typically used as Foreign Keys. That is, there are other tables and databases that store identity column values instead of duplicating rows. If you update an identity column, all foreign keys will break, so don't do it. Even if you think it's not really a foreign key, or you're sure you can update all the other databases, this is how SQL works so don't try to “work around” it.

If you are setting up a new database, create new keys in the new database, don't change existing keys.

Comment: One can still update an `IDENTITY COLUMN` by using the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <<table>> ON` session setting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fooa5dd49f2-45c7-44a8-b182-e0a5e5c373ee.aspx

Comment: @dour that's good advice, but I'm wondering more about the reason why insert is allowed, but update isn't.  It could be for the reasons you stated, to prevent people from getting themselves into trouble, but I was hoping someone could substantiate it.

Comment: @wdosanjos, no you can't, that's why it's called IDENTITY_INSERT and not IDENTITY_UPDATE!

Comment: @kristianp, inserting a new identity cannot cause an anomaly because no foreign key could depend on an identity that doesn't already exist.